# Can't find my source file even it's already in the pythonpath directory

Tags: python, pythonpath

On Windows 10, Python 3.6.1, after I added `E:\learning python exercise`  in `PYTHONPATH`  by the GUI or through .pth file.  Ihen C checked the `os.sys.path`, it reads:

[image: checking PYTHONPATH]

But when I want to run a file through the `cmd` prompt, it pops out error:

[image: error!]

Comment: Please don't supply external links in your question.  You should copy and paste the text into your question instead.

Comment: thank you very much for your generous help，it's my first stackoverflow question，sorry for the unconvenient.

Comment: Sorry, but pasting a graphic is not acceptable practice either.  You should copy and paste the text, not a screen-shot.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not use PYTHONPATH for scripts - it uses them for modules.  So you could try:

```
python -m script1
```

but that is not the way scripts should be run.  You should supply the path name to python or assume it is in the current directory. For example:

python "E:\learning python exercise\script1.py"

The double quotes are required because you have elected to have spaces in your directory name - I suggest that you might want to stop doing that, spaces in path names just makes life more difficult.

Alternatively, change your current directory, either using the `cd` command or by setting the "start in" properties to your `cmd.exe` shortcut.  For example:

```
cd "E:\learning python exercise"
python script1.py
```

You only have to do the `cd` once in each `cmd.exe` session.

If you have setup the filename association for python (should have been done at installation time), then you should only need:

```
cd "E:\learning python exercise"
script1.py
```